# StackOverflow Exception on @Html.Action()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to get my login partial to read the user's first and last name from my database.  Therefore, I am trying to call an action from my layout instead of the view partial.

```
@If Request.IsAuthenticated Then

      @<text><div class="authBox">Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
      </div></text>

Else
```

I am getting a stack overflow exception on this line in my layout:

```
@Html.Action("RenderLogOnPartial", "Employee")
```

Here is the action I am calling:

```
    ' 
    ' GET: /Employee/RenderLogOnPartial
    Public Function RenderLogOnPartial() As ViewResult

        Return View("_LogOnWithValidationPartial")

    End Function
```

What can I do to get the first and last name into my view partial?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views will use your layout, which will call your action again, hence the stackoverflow.

Try

```
Return PartialView("_LogOnWithValidationPartial")
```

Comment: I didn't know it was such an option to render a partial view.  Thanks.